# Visual Basic Radio Button Calculations

Tags: vb.net

I am using Radio buttons in VB for first and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The click event is suppose to multiply two inputs but no matter what figure input,  the result comes back 0.

The code I am working with is:

back

```
Dim decTotal As Decimal       'Total charge for choice plan

Dim intMinutes As Integer         'Duration of phone calls
 　
 'Declare constants for Rates

 Const decDaytimeRate As Decimal = 0.07D

Const decEveningRate As Decimal = 0.12D

Const decOffPeakRate As Decimal = 0.05D
　
 'Dispay Total charge

lblTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")
　
　
　

'Calculate total amount the user is expected to pay according to rate plan

 If radDaytime.Checked = True Then

decTotal = intMinutes * decDaytimeRate

End If

 If radEvening.Checked = True Then

 decTotal = decEveningRate * intMinutes

End If
```

I am sure it is an easy fix since I am not throwing any error messages but I am stuck nonetheless.

Comment: what do you mean "the result comes back" click events do not return a value.  please format your code

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. The results when the calculate button is clicked on returns a 0.00 value.

Comment: Set the lblTotal.Text property **after** you made the calculation, not before.

Answer (score 0):

Move the lblTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("c") line to the end. It's displaying the result before you calculate it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes perfect sense to set it after the calculation but the result is still the same.

Comment: Change intMinutes to be a decimal. I think the problem is that VB is rounding the decimal to an int (0) so anything multipled by 0 is... 0. Alternatively you could keep intMinutes as a Int but wrap the intMinutes in the calculations with Decimal.Parse(intMinutes): e.g.   decTotal = decEveningRate * Decimal.Parse(intMinutes)

Comment: IntMinutes is the name for the text box where the user enters the minutes they plan to use. I kept it as an Integer and parsed it like so  ..... Decimal.TryParse(txtMinutes.Text, intMinutes)

Comment: Oh no, TryParse fixed it. Thank you so much for your help :)